# TypeScript - Why does a name get displayed when there is a private class inside a public constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-class

I have this Try it Yourself TypeScript Parameter Properties example from W3Schools in the screenshot below.

[image: TypeScript Classes Parameter Properties example]

I am a bit confused as to why the name Jane gets displayed to the screen when there is this code.

My understanding is that the code below assigns a a variable to a class Person

```
const person = new Person ("Jane")
```

console.log code calls a getName() function with this code

```
console.log(person.getName())
```

Inside class Person, a public visibility modifier has a function that returns a name with

```
public getName(): string  { 
   return this.name; 
}
```

But how can it get the name when this code has a private member variable inside a public constructor

```
public constructor(private name: string) {}
```

I though that a private member only allows access to a class member (in this case name) from within the class

How does it work when you have a private member within a public constructor like this ?

If someone can give me a good understanding on why it can still work like this, then that will be appreciated help, thanks ?

Comment: But the private member it is being accessed within the class and your example.

Comment: The point of `private` is to hide implementation details or to restrict access (i.e. a `get` but not a `set` method). You still need to "expose" an interface to be able to *use* the class. So the public `getName` *can* access *and return* the string held in the private variable `name`.

Comment: The critical part that I am trying to understand with this is, why does the example have public constructor( private name: string ) {} when it could just have public constructor(name: string) {} ? I say this because to me it seems that the private part does not have any effect on public constructor.

Comment: One last point question that I have on this.
With this example, why does it need a public constructor(private: string) {} for declaring name property, when it could just declare the name in the function public(getName(): string)  { return this.name; } ?
Is this because a class is meant to have a constructor in TypeScript ?

Answer (score 0):

Note:- Constructor of class 'Person' is public and it can be accessible within & outside of the class declaration.

```
"use strict";

class Person {
    public constructor(private name: string) { }
    public getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}

const person  = new Person("Jane");

console.log(person);
```

Output you will get:

```
Person: { "name": "Jane" }
```

Now, If you don't want to access `class 'Person'` out side then you need to change public access modifiers to private and then that member can only accessible within the class declaration.

```
"use strict";

class Person {
    private constructor(private name: string) { }
    private getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}

const person  = new Person("Jane");

console.log(person);
```

Error you will get:

1. Constructor of class 'Person' is private and only accessible within
   the class declaration.
2. 'getName' is declared but its value is never read.

For more details please check this link [typescriptlang access modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at this question in terms of what the code means from 2 perspectives.

1. Code as it is shown in screenshot
2. How the private part works

Here is code from screenshot explained :

```
class Person {
// A class is created here and this is a template for the object within it.
  
  public constructor(private name: string) {}
  /* A constructor is a method that runs every time a new instance of a 
     class is created. It is a method called when creating an object and 
     it can be used to initialize values in a class. 
     By default constructors use a public visibility modifier, so 
     this is same as constructor(private name: string). */

  /* (private name: string) is a parameter of string type that can be 
     used as a class member for getName() function only within this 
     class. */

  public getName(): string {
  // A function that gets name parameter as a string type.

    return this.name;
    /* Now we want to access a name member of this class, which is the 
       parameter here and display property value as a string on screen. 
    */
  }
}
      
const person = new Person("Jane");
/* Here an object of a class is created using new keyword that 
   creates a new instance of a class, so object person is of type 
   Person class.
   Happens first in process, where it assigns an object as a variable to 
   Person class and includes a name parameter with a property value of 
   Jane. */

console.log(person.getName());
/* Console calls a getName() function in Class Person by using an 
   internal method with public getName(): string . That picks up a name 
   parameter with string type from public constructor and displays 
   property value on screen. */
```

The result of this code, is that Jane gets displayed on screen

This works because a parameter method in public constructor is used for a name property that uses a public getName() function to allow access to a class member from anywhere.

It also works because we have console code use a function below to access a property value within class :

```
console.log(person.getName());
```

> You can also change code below Class Person to access whole class

```
const person = new Person("Jane");

console.log(person);
```

and it works, as well with this output.

```
Person: { "name": "Jane" }
```

Now if we were to change the way we access with person.name = "Jane" as shown with code below

```
class Person {
  //Can use private name: string here and it will work in same way

    public constructor(private name: string) {
    // Can use public constructor(name) here and it will work in same way

  }

  public getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }
}
      
const person = new Person("Jane");

person.name = "Jane"

console.log(person);
```

Then following error appears with

> prog.ts(17,8): error TS2341: Property 'name' is private and only
> accessible within class 'Person'.

So this shows that a private class member cannot be accessed outside of a class as a property of an object.

The process also works the same with readonly as well in terms of access

and readonly prevents a class member from being changed with this error.

> prog.ts(16,8): error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a
> read-only property.

Lastly if all class members are private, you cannot access a property from any of these methods, I have mentioned and will get a private error.